# Allow copy, paste and cut in textarea (Building keybord)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keyboard, custom-keyboard

I am building keyboard want allow users to copy, paste, cut from keyboard short keys like ctrl+C, ctrl+v ctrl+x.
It works well but when I copy, paste or cut any text in text area. Later on I can not type any more text or edit current pasted text until I refresh the page.

```
<textarea id="write"></textarea>
```

jQuery Code:

```
$write = $('#write'); $write.keydown(function (event) {
  if(!event.ctrlKey) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $write.html($write.html() + ' tmp'); 
  } 
});
```

It's working good but when I paste or cut text from textarea after that this is not work. I check the  console and see text is adding in textarea tags but not shown in textarea.
Here is working link
 http://projects.imube.com/keyboard/

[Keyboard](http://projects.imube.com/keyboard/)

Comment: Do you mean to disable mouse right click, cut, copy and paste using jQuery? And should only be allowed by keyboard?

Comment: No dear. i want to allow user to do all this. not disable. Please read the full.

Comment: It is working fine for me. I am able to cut/copy/paste in both keyboard and by using click. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Yes it work. But after cut, copy or paste. You can not add more text by using keyboard. this is the problem.

Comment: Comment out this line `event.preventDefault();`.

Comment: Then I can not type my custom characters. The other language than english.

Comment: Use `val()` not `html()` to set and get value of textarea. Also provide a [mcve]